# Where to find 'javax.lang' and 'javax.annotation' in ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm working on a java project which depends on both 'javax.lang' and 'javax.annotation'. I have jre/jdk installed, a lot of other javax.* on the classpath, and I develop in Java everyday. However, these two packages remain not found.

Thank you

Comment: Did you set up your `JAVA_HOME` and your `PATH` environment variables?

Comment: Which Java version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`javax.lang` and `javax.annotation` appear to be available since version Java 6. They're not present in Java 5 or earlier versions. You ought to be using a Java 6 JDK for the purpose of development.

Answer (score 1):

Both exist in the main jar file, located at `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/lib/rt.jar`.

make sure that you have your JAVA_HOME system property points to the right library, should be /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun.

The is is relevant if you use openjdk as well (the directory name may change)